# Debug azure function 1.0 in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

What is the proper way to use the azure function core tools and debug a V1 nodejs function locally using visual studio code?

For a new V2 function everything works great.  I cannot update to V2 functions however.  The build process is out of my control and attempting to do so broke the build.

The project started with:

```
"azure-functions-cli": "1.0.0-beta.94",
```

I couldn't get that to work and upgraded to:

```
"azure-functions-core-tools": "^1.0.20",
```

I cannot update to the latest 2.x version because I get errors.  Initially:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: The host.json file is missing the required 'version' property. See https://aka.ms/functions-hostjson for steps to migrate the configuration file.

Trying just adding the version (either 1.0 or 2.0) didn't work.

So back to 1.0.20.  I run it and I see this:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
```

That's great because it matches my launch config:

```
{
    "name": "Crazy attempt",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 5858,
},
```

Actually I can attach and it seems to work.  My breakpoints look good, and changes to my code appear without restarting the function host.  However, none of my breakpoints get hit.  When I kill the function host the debugger quits in my vscode window.  I know I have to be doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 0):

I had to start with this:

```
func host start --debug VSCode
```

Comment: You should expand on your answer; explaining what it's doing